# How can I conform to ShapeStyle protocol in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am looking to conform to ShapeStyle, the goal is just conforming to ShapeStyle(Nothing more and nothing less).

Here is my code and the issue:

```
struct MyContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(RedView())
    }
}

struct RedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

So I know I could use `Color.red` directly instead of a view, but as I said, the goal of this question is conformation to ShapeStyle. For those going to share apple developer link about ShapeStyle, I have to say I was there before.

Error:

> Instance method 'fill(_:style:)' requires that 'RedView' conform to 'ShapeStyle'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** *below is only for demo, because all used API are private (by convention, not by design), so reaction of Apple if you submit app with such code to AppStore is unpredictable.*

**Note: as used interfaces are private they can be changed with any new version.**

Main part:

```
  public func _apply(to shape: inout SwiftUI._ShapeStyle_Shape) {
    Color.red._apply(to: &shape)  // << here !!
  }
```

Which gives on Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

Complete [findings and code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/CustomShapeStyle.md)

Comment: Thanks, I needed just for learning, not going to use it in real project.

Answer (score 6):

### iOS 17+

You can now conform to `ShapeStyle` natively by implementing the [`resolve(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/resolve(in:)-6feyg?changes=l__3_5) method.

```
struct RedShapeStyle: ShapeStyle {
    func resolve(in environment: EnvironmentValues) -> some ShapeStyle {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want *any kind of View* to conform to `ShapeStyle`, then @Asperi provided here the answer.

If you want a `Color` to conform to `ShapeStyle` like in your example, it already adopts that protocol, so you just need a little tweak to make it work, like this:

```
struct RedView {
    var render: some ShapeStyle {
        Color.red
    }
}

struct MyContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(RedView().render)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [ShapeStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/):

> You don’t use the `ShapeStyle` protocol directly. Instead, use one of the concrete styles that SwiftUI defines. To indicate a specific color or pattern, you can use `Color` or the style returned by `image(_:sourceRect:scale:)`, or one of the gradient types, like the one returned by `radialGradient(_:center:startRadius:endRadius:)`. To set a color that’s appropriate for a given context on a given platform, use one of the semantic styles, like `background` or `primary`.

I believe what you're trying to do can be achieved with:

```swift
struct MyContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: @iosDev it's not possible to write your own conformances to ShapeStyle. Every requirement is hidden and so you get strange compiler errors if you try.

Comment: @Bbrk24: I was hoping it that it would be a way or even the last try from other people for solving the issue, but I understand your point. thanks

Comment: @Bbrk24: What do you mean by "hidden"?

Comment: @flarn2006 It's been long enough since I wrote that that I don't quite remember for sure. From what I remember, the declaration looks like `protocol ShapeStyle {}`, so a struct like `struct Foo: ShapeStyle {}` will compile. However, if you want it to do anything short of nothing, you have to use internal functions with underscored names, like the `_apply(to:)` @Asperi found. But it's easy to accidentally cause errors like this ime, and as they said in their answer, the function's name or purpose is subject to change at any time without warning in future versions of iOS.

Comment: @Bbrk24 (or anyone who can answer): does Xcode provide any known means, officially documented or otherwise, to disable this hiding of members?